# Rebuild a polygon so it doesn't self intersect

Tags: graphics, geometry

If you consider the following `Polygon`:

```
coor = {{6, 0}, {6, 1}, {4, 0}, {5, 2}};
(* and coor = {{7, 2}, {7, 1}, {5, 2}, {6, 1}} *)
pol = Polygon@coor;
Graphics@pol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I would like to know if there is any way to rebuild it *automatically* in order to remove the self intersection.

Self intersection can be check thanks to [J.M.'s comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25348/how-can-i-draw-a-polygon-from-a-set-of-angles/25360#comment78601_25360) by:

```
interPolQ = Not@Graphics`Mesh`SimplePolygonQ[#]&;
interPolQ@pol
```

> True

Knowing that `` Graphics`Mesh`SimplePolygonQ[] `` is undocumented I'm wondering if there is a hidden built-in function for that purpose as well.

---

The output should look like the following and have for coordinates `desiredcoor`:

```
coor = {{6, 0}, {6, 1}, {4, 0}, {5, 2}};
desiredcoor = {{4, 0}, {6, 0}, {6, 1}, {5, 2}};
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Dashed], FaceForm@Opacity@.2, Polygon@{coor, desiredcoor}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I guess you're not after the convex hull, but for clarity you could show an example showing the before and after and also showing that the result isn't the convex hull

Comment: The result should fill the white spaces as well. I'm going to edit it.

Comment: @belisarius I might need `ConvexHull` indeed.. :) That's uber perfect. I still don't know what a convex hull is but at least I know what it does.

Comment: Be careful. The convex hull may "eat up" some of your vertices. For example, if you add one more vertex inside your grayed area, it won't show up in the convex hull.

Comment: Previously: @ybeltukov's ["deintersection" algorithm](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32785/484).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question is a little underspecified, so I'll discuss two options.

```
SeedRandom[0];
coords = RandomReal[1, {6, 2}];
drawPolygon[coords_, color_] := {PointSize[Large], color, Point@coords, 
  FaceForm[Opacity[0.2]], EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, color]], Polygon@coords}
Graphics[drawPolygon[coords, Red]]
```

[image]

As suggested by @belisarius, the convex hull does not self-intersect, but can drop points:

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];
chCoords = coords[[ConvexHull[coords]]];
Graphics[drawPolygon[chCoords, Darker@Green]]
```

[image]

If you want to preserve all the points but remove self-intersections, you can try using the travelling salesman tour:

```
stCoords = coords[[Last@FindShortestTour[coords]]];
Graphics[drawPolygon[stCoords, Blue]]
```

[image]

This approach solves a strictly harder problem than just finding an intersection-free polygon, though, so maybe a simpler solution is possible.

---

**Caveat:** For large datasets, Mathematica finds a suboptimal tour, and it's possible that the tour self-intersects.

```
coords = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {200, 2}];
stCoords = coords[[Last@FindShortestTour[coords]]];
Graphics[drawPolygon[stCoords, Blue]]
```

[image]

To remove those intersections, we can use @ybeltukov's ["deintersection" algorithm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32785/484) on the computed tour.

```
SignedArea[p1_, p2_, p3_] := 
  0.5 (#1[[2]] #2[[1]] - #1[[1]] #2[[2]]) &[p2 - p1, p3 - p1];
IntersectionQ[p1_, p2_, p3_, p4_] := 
  SignedArea[p1, p2, p3] SignedArea[p1, p2, p4] < 0 && 
   SignedArea[p3, p4, p1] SignedArea[p3, p4, p2] < 0;
Deintersect[p_] := 
  Append[p, 
     p[[1]]] //. {s1___, p1_, p2_, s2___, p3_, p4_, s3___} /; 
      IntersectionQ[p1, p2, p3, p4] :> ({s1, p1, p3, 
       Sequence @@ Reverse@{s2}, p2, p4, s3}) // Most;
dstCoords = Deintersect[stCoords];
Graphics[drawPolygon[dstCoords, Purple]]
```

[image]

One might ask, why not simply apply `Deintersect` on the original coordinates? Well, one can, but it takes an extremely long time.

```
dCoords = Deintersect[coords];
Graphics[drawPolygon[dCoords, Orange]]
```

[image]

Comment: It would be interesting to see where `ShortestTour` draws the line in terms of an optimal solution (since it claims to find these for "small" numbers of vertices).

Comment: It's weird that `FindShortestTour` doesn't remove intersections as a post-processing step. IIRC, finding&removing intersections is a O(n*log(n)) operation if done right, and it's guaranteed to make the tour shorter.

Comment: These are both good points that I don't know the answer to! =)

Comment: While you are both here, thanks for the good answers :) I'm having a hard time trying to find the best. I assume that the _only_ intersection is going to be a bad point for @RahulNarain ;o) :)

Comment: @Öskå: As I said, the problem is underspecified, so there are lots of valid solutions, and what is best depends on what you want. If you want a spiky polygon, use nikie's. If you want a wiggly polygon, use mine. :)

Comment: I'm not really into spikes though.. :)

Comment: @Öskå: To be fair, nikie's approach is extremely fast to compute, while mine starts to get pretty slow for large polygons.

Comment: The problem is that nikie's answer doesn't seem to work with my test case. See [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tBQaJ.png).

Comment: @Öskå: You're right, I forgot that `SortBy` treats exact values and machine-precision values differently. Try using `N@ArcTan[...` or `N[pts]` instead, then `SortBy` should sort them properly.

Answer (score 14):

One simple way to get an intersection-free tour would be to

- choose a center point (e.g. arithmetic mean of the vertices)
- sort the other points clockwise around that center

then the polygon should be the graph of a positive function in a polar plot, so it shouldn't intersect.

I've tested it with some random point sets:

```
pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {200, 2}];
ListLinePlot[Append[pts, pts[[1]]], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
(* get the center point *)
center = Mean[pts];

(* sort by angle *)
pts = SortBy[pts, N[ArcTan @@ (# - center)] &];

(* display result *)
ListLinePlot[Append[pts, pts[[1]]], Epilog -> {Red, Point[center]}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

I think if two points get the same angle from the starting point, this should still work, but if there's a chance that three or more points lie on a straight line through the starting point, you should sort by `{angle, radius}` instead.

Comment: "…you should sort by `{angle, radius}` instead." - that is, `SortBy[pts, {N[ArcTan @@ (# - center)] &, N[EuclideanDistance[center, #]] &}]`