# Some problems about ListPlot3D, plot 6 faces of a 3D region

Tags: graphics3d, plotting

I get the data of six faces of a 3D region.

```
datafront={{65, 5, 0.1}, {70, 10, 0.1}, {70, 15, 0.1}, {75, 20, 0.1}, {75, 25, 
  0.1}, {80, 30, 0.1}, {80, 35, 0.1}, {60, 5, 0.15}, {65, 10, 
  0.15}, {65, 15, 0.15}, {70, 20, 0.15}, {75, 25, 0.15}, {75, 30, 
  0.15}, {80, 35, 0.15}, {55, 5, 0.2}, {60, 10, 0.2}, {65, 15, 
  0.2}, {65, 20, 0.2}, {70, 25, 0.2}, {75, 30, 0.2}, {75, 35, 
  0.2}, {50, 5, 0.25}, {55, 10, 0.25}, {60, 15, 0.25}, {65, 20, 
  0.25}, {70, 25, 0.25}, {70, 30, 0.25}, {75, 35, 0.25}, {45, 5, 
  0.3}, {50, 10, 0.3}, {55, 15, 0.3}, {60, 20, 0.3}, {65, 25, 
  0.3}, {70, 30, 0.3}, {75, 35, 0.3}, {45, 5, 0.35}, {50, 10, 
  0.35}, {55, 15, 0.35}, {60, 20, 0.35}, {65, 25, 0.35}, {70, 30, 
  0.35}, {70, 35, 0.35}, {40, 5, 0.4}, {45, 10, 0.4}, {50, 15, 
  0.4}, {55, 20, 0.4}, {60, 25, 0.4}, {65, 30, 0.4}, {70, 35, 
  0.4}, {35, 5, 0.45}, {40, 10, 0.45}, {45, 15, 0.45}, {55, 20, 
  0.45}, {60, 25, 0.45}, {65, 30, 0.45}, {70, 35, 0.45}, {35, 5, 
  0.5}, {40, 10, 0.5}, {45, 15, 0.5}, {50, 20, 0.5}, {55, 25, 
  0.5}, {60, 30, 0.5}, {65, 35, 0.5}, {30, 5, 0.55}, {35, 10, 
  0.55}, {40, 15, 0.55}, {45, 20, 0.55}, {55, 25, 0.55}, {60, 30, 
  0.55}, {65, 35, 0.55}, {30, 5, 0.6}, {30, 10, 0.6}, {40, 15, 
  0.6}, {45, 20, 0.6}, {50, 25, 0.6}, {55, 30, 0.6}, {60, 35, 
  0.6}, {25, 5, 0.65}, {30, 10, 0.65}, {35, 15, 0.65}, {40, 20, 
  0.65}, {50, 25, 0.65}, {55, 30, 0.65}, {60, 35, 0.65}, {20, 5, 
  0.7}, {25, 10, 0.7}, {30, 15, 0.7}, {40, 20, 0.7}, {45, 25, 
  0.7}, {50, 30, 0.7}, {55, 35, 0.7}, {20, 5, 0.75}, {25, 10, 
  0.75}, {30, 15, 0.75}, {35, 20, 0.75}, {40, 25, 0.75}, {50, 30, 
  0.75}, {55, 35, 0.75}, {15, 5, 0.8}, {20, 10, 0.8}, {25, 15, 
  0.8}, {30, 20, 0.8}, {35, 25, 0.8}, {45, 30, 0.8}, {50, 35, 
  0.8}, {15, 5, 0.85}, {15, 10, 0.85}, {20, 15, 0.85}, {25, 20, 
  0.85}, {35, 25, 0.85}, {40, 30, 0.85}, {45, 35, 0.85}, {10, 5, 
  0.9}, {10, 10, 0.9}, {15, 15, 0.9}, {20, 20, 0.9}, {25, 25, 
  0.9}, {35, 30, 0.9}, {40, 35, 0.9}};
databack={{80, 5, 0.1}, {80, 10, 0.1}, {80, 15, 0.1}, {80, 20, 0.1}, {80, 25, 
  0.1}, {80, 30, 0.1}, {80, 35, 0.1}, {80, 5, 0.15}, {80, 10, 
  0.15}, {80, 15, 0.15}, {80, 20, 0.15}, {80, 25, 0.15}, {80, 30, 
  0.15}, {80, 35, 0.15}, {80, 5, 0.2}, {80, 10, 0.2}, {80, 15, 
  0.2}, {80, 20, 0.2}, {80, 25, 0.2}, {80, 30, 0.2}, {80, 35, 
  0.2}, {80, 5, 0.25}, {80, 10, 0.25}, {80, 15, 0.25}, {80, 20, 
  0.25}, {80, 25, 0.25}, {80, 30, 0.25}, {80, 35, 0.25}, {80, 5, 
  0.3}, {80, 10, 0.3}, {80, 15, 0.3}, {80, 20, 0.3}, {80, 25, 
  0.3}, {80, 30, 0.3}, {80, 35, 0.3}, {80, 5, 0.35}, {80, 10, 
  0.35}, {80, 15, 0.35}, {80, 20, 0.35}, {80, 25, 0.35}, {80, 30, 
  0.35}, {80, 35, 0.35}, {80, 5, 0.4}, {80, 10, 0.4}, {80, 15, 
  0.4}, {80, 20, 0.4}, {80, 25, 0.4}, {80, 30, 0.4}, {80, 35, 
  0.4}, {80, 5, 0.45}, {80, 10, 0.45}, {80, 15, 0.45}, {80, 20, 
  0.45}, {80, 25, 0.45}, {80, 30, 0.45}, {80, 35, 0.45}, {80, 5, 
  0.5}, {80, 10, 0.5}, {80, 15, 0.5}, {80, 20, 0.5}, {80, 25, 
  0.5}, {80, 30, 0.5}, {80, 35, 0.5}, {80, 5, 0.55}, {80, 10, 
  0.55}, {80, 15, 0.55}, {80, 20, 0.55}, {80, 25, 0.55}, {80, 30, 
  0.55}, {80, 35, 0.55}, {80, 5, 0.6}, {80, 10, 0.6}, {80, 15, 
  0.6}, {80, 20, 0.6}, {80, 25, 0.6}, {80, 30, 0.6}, {80, 35, 
  0.6}, {80, 5, 0.65}, {80, 10, 0.65}, {80, 15, 0.65}, {80, 20, 
  0.65}, {80, 25, 0.65}, {80, 30, 0.65}, {80, 35, 0.65}, {80, 5, 
  0.7}, {80, 10, 0.7}, {80, 15, 0.7}, {80, 20, 0.7}, {80, 25, 
  0.7}, {80, 30, 0.7}, {80, 35, 0.7}, {80, 5, 0.75}, {80, 10, 
  0.75}, {80, 15, 0.75}, {80, 20, 0.75}, {80, 25, 0.75}, {80, 30, 
  0.75}, {80, 35, 0.75}, {80, 5, 0.8}, {80, 10, 0.8}, {80, 15, 
  0.8}, {80, 20, 0.8}, {80, 25, 0.8}, {80, 30, 0.8}, {80, 35, 
  0.8}, {80, 5, 0.85}, {80, 10, 0.85}, {80, 15, 0.85}, {80, 20, 
  0.85}, {80, 25, 0.85}, {80, 30, 0.85}, {80, 35, 0.85}, {80, 5, 
  0.9}, {80, 10, 0.9}, {80, 15, 0.9}, {80, 20, 0.9}, {80, 25, 
  0.9}, {80, 30, 0.9}, {80, 35, 0.9}};
datatop={{65, 5, 0.1}, {70, 5, 0.1}, {75, 5, 0.1}, {80, 5, 0.1}, {70, 10, 
  0.1}, {75, 10, 0.1}, {80, 10, 0.1}, {70, 15, 0.1}, {75, 15, 
  0.1}, {80, 15, 0.1}, {75, 20, 0.1}, {80, 20, 0.1}, {75, 25, 
  0.1}, {80, 25, 0.1}, {80, 30, 0.1}, {80, 35, 0.1}};
databottom={{10, 5, 0.9}, {15, 5, 0.9}, {20, 5, 0.9}, {25, 5, 0.9}, {30, 5, 
  0.9}, {35, 5, 0.9}, {40, 5, 0.9}, {45, 5, 0.9}, {50, 5, 0.9}, {55, 
  5, 0.9}, {60, 5, 0.9}, {65, 5, 0.9}, {70, 5, 0.9}, {75, 5, 
  0.9}, {80, 5, 0.9}, {10, 10, 0.9}, {15, 10, 0.9}, {20, 10, 
  0.9}, {25, 10, 0.9}, {30, 10, 0.9}, {35, 10, 0.9}, {40, 10, 
  0.9}, {45, 10, 0.9}, {50, 10, 0.9}, {55, 10, 0.9}, {60, 10, 
  0.9}, {65, 10, 0.9}, {70, 10, 0.9}, {75, 10, 0.9}, {80, 10, 
  0.9}, {15, 15, 0.9}, {20, 15, 0.9}, {25, 15, 0.9}, {30, 15, 
  0.9}, {35, 15, 0.9}, {40, 15, 0.9}, {45, 15, 0.9}, {50, 15, 
  0.9}, {55, 15, 0.9}, {60, 15, 0.9}, {65, 15, 0.9}, {70, 15, 
  0.9}, {75, 15, 0.9}, {80, 15, 0.9}, {20, 20, 0.9}, {25, 20, 
  0.9}, {30, 20, 0.9}, {35, 20, 0.9}, {40, 20, 0.9}, {45, 20, 
  0.9}, {50, 20, 0.9}, {55, 20, 0.9}, {60, 20, 0.9}, {65, 20, 
  0.9}, {70, 20, 0.9}, {75, 20, 0.9}, {80, 20, 0.9}, {25, 25, 
  0.9}, {30, 25, 0.9}, {35, 25, 0.9}, {40, 25, 0.9}, {45, 25, 
  0.9}, {50, 25, 0.9}, {55, 25, 0.9}, {60, 25, 0.9}, {65, 25, 
  0.9}, {70, 25, 0.9}, {75, 25, 0.9}, {80, 25, 0.9}, {35, 30, 
  0.9}, {40, 30, 0.9}, {45, 30, 0.9}, {50, 30, 0.9}, {55, 30, 
  0.9}, {60, 30, 0.9}, {65, 30, 0.9}, {70, 30, 0.9}, {75, 30, 
  0.9}, {80, 30, 0.9}, {40, 35, 0.9}, {45, 35, 0.9}, {50, 35, 
  0.9}, {55, 35, 0.9}, {60, 35, 0.9}, {65, 35, 0.9}, {70, 35, 
  0.9}, {75, 35, 0.9}, {80, 35, 0.9}};
dataleft={{10, 5, 0.9}, {15, 5, 0.8}, {15, 5, 0.85}, {15, 5, 0.9}, {20, 5, 
  0.7}, {20, 5, 0.75}, {20, 5, 0.8}, {20, 5, 0.85}, {20, 5, 0.9}, {25,
   5, 0.65}, {25, 5, 0.7}, {25, 5, 0.75}, {25, 5, 0.8}, {25, 5, 
  0.85}, {25, 5, 0.9}, {30, 5, 0.55}, {30, 5, 0.6}, {30, 5, 
  0.65}, {30, 5, 0.7}, {30, 5, 0.75}, {30, 5, 0.8}, {30, 5, 
  0.85}, {30, 5, 0.9}, {35, 5, 0.45}, {35, 5, 0.5}, {35, 5, 
  0.55}, {35, 5, 0.6}, {35, 5, 0.65}, {35, 5, 0.7}, {35, 5, 
  0.75}, {35, 5, 0.8}, {35, 5, 0.85}, {35, 5, 0.9}, {40, 5, 0.4}, {40,
   5, 0.45}, {40, 5, 0.5}, {40, 5, 0.55}, {40, 5, 0.6}, {40, 5, 
  0.65}, {40, 5, 0.7}, {40, 5, 0.75}, {40, 5, 0.8}, {40, 5, 
  0.85}, {40, 5, 0.9}, {45, 5, 0.3}, {45, 5, 0.35}, {45, 5, 0.4}, {45,
   5, 0.45}, {45, 5, 0.5}, {45, 5, 0.55}, {45, 5, 0.6}, {45, 5, 
  0.65}, {45, 5, 0.7}, {45, 5, 0.75}, {45, 5, 0.8}, {45, 5, 
  0.85}, {45, 5, 0.9}, {50, 5, 0.25}, {50, 5, 0.3}, {50, 5, 
  0.35}, {50, 5, 0.4}, {50, 5, 0.45}, {50, 5, 0.5}, {50, 5, 
  0.55}, {50, 5, 0.6}, {50, 5, 0.65}, {50, 5, 0.7}, {50, 5, 
  0.75}, {50, 5, 0.8}, {50, 5, 0.85}, {50, 5, 0.9}, {55, 5, 0.2}, {55,
   5, 0.25}, {55, 5, 0.3}, {55, 5, 0.35}, {55, 5, 0.4}, {55, 5, 
  0.45}, {55, 5, 0.5}, {55, 5, 0.55}, {55, 5, 0.6}, {55, 5, 
  0.65}, {55, 5, 0.7}, {55, 5, 0.75}, {55, 5, 0.8}, {55, 5, 
  0.85}, {55, 5, 0.9}, {60, 5, 0.15}, {60, 5, 0.2}, {60, 5, 
  0.25}, {60, 5, 0.3}, {60, 5, 0.35}, {60, 5, 0.4}, {60, 5, 
  0.45}, {60, 5, 0.5}, {60, 5, 0.55}, {60, 5, 0.6}, {60, 5, 
  0.65}, {60, 5, 0.7}, {60, 5, 0.75}, {60, 5, 0.8}, {60, 5, 
  0.85}, {60, 5, 0.9}, {65, 5, 0.1}, {65, 5, 0.15}, {65, 5, 0.2}, {65,
   5, 0.25}, {65, 5, 0.3}, {65, 5, 0.35}, {65, 5, 0.4}, {65, 5, 
  0.45}, {65, 5, 0.5}, {65, 5, 0.55}, {65, 5, 0.6}, {65, 5, 
  0.65}, {65, 5, 0.7}, {65, 5, 0.75}, {65, 5, 0.8}, {65, 5, 
  0.85}, {65, 5, 0.9}, {70, 5, 0.1}, {70, 5, 0.15}, {70, 5, 0.2}, {70,
   5, 0.25}, {70, 5, 0.3}, {70, 5, 0.35}, {70, 5, 0.4}, {70, 5, 
  0.45}, {70, 5, 0.5}, {70, 5, 0.55}, {70, 5, 0.6}, {70, 5, 
  0.65}, {70, 5, 0.7}, {70, 5, 0.75}, {70, 5, 0.8}, {70, 5, 
  0.85}, {70, 5, 0.9}, {75, 5, 0.1}, {75, 5, 0.15}, {75, 5, 0.2}, {75,
   5, 0.25}, {75, 5, 0.3}, {75, 5, 0.35}, {75, 5, 0.4}, {75, 5, 
  0.45}, {75, 5, 0.5}, {75, 5, 0.55}, {75, 5, 0.6}, {75, 5, 
  0.65}, {75, 5, 0.7}, {75, 5, 0.75}, {75, 5, 0.8}, {75, 5, 
  0.85}, {75, 5, 0.9}, {80, 5, 0.1}, {80, 5, 0.15}, {80, 5, 0.2}, {80,
   5, 0.25}, {80, 5, 0.3}, {80, 5, 0.35}, {80, 5, 0.4}, {80, 5, 
  0.45}, {80, 5, 0.5}, {80, 5, 0.55}, {80, 5, 0.6}, {80, 5, 
  0.65}, {80, 5, 0.7}, {80, 5, 0.75}, {80, 5, 0.8}, {80, 5, 
  0.85}, {80, 5, 0.9}};
dataright={{40, 35, 0.9}, {45, 35, 0.85}, {45, 35, 0.9}, {50, 35, 0.8}, {50, 35,
   0.85}, {50, 35, 0.9}, {55, 35, 0.7}, {55, 35, 0.75}, {55, 35, 
  0.8}, {55, 35, 0.85}, {55, 35, 0.9}, {60, 35, 0.6}, {60, 35, 
  0.65}, {60, 35, 0.7}, {60, 35, 0.75}, {60, 35, 0.8}, {60, 35, 
  0.85}, {60, 35, 0.9}, {65, 35, 0.5}, {65, 35, 0.55}, {65, 35, 
  0.6}, {65, 35, 0.65}, {65, 35, 0.7}, {65, 35, 0.75}, {65, 35, 
  0.8}, {65, 35, 0.85}, {65, 35, 0.9}, {70, 35, 0.35}, {70, 35, 
  0.4}, {70, 35, 0.45}, {70, 35, 0.5}, {70, 35, 0.55}, {70, 35, 
  0.6}, {70, 35, 0.65}, {70, 35, 0.7}, {70, 35, 0.75}, {70, 35, 
  0.8}, {70, 35, 0.85}, {70, 35, 0.9}, {75, 35, 0.2}, {75, 35, 
  0.25}, {75, 35, 0.3}, {75, 35, 0.35}, {75, 35, 0.4}, {75, 35, 
  0.45}, {75, 35, 0.5}, {75, 35, 0.55}, {75, 35, 0.6}, {75, 35, 
  0.65}, {75, 35, 0.7}, {75, 35, 0.75}, {75, 35, 0.8}, {75, 35, 
  0.85}, {75, 35, 0.9}, {80, 35, 0.1}, {80, 35, 0.15}, {80, 35, 
  0.2}, {80, 35, 0.25}, {80, 35, 0.3}, {80, 35, 0.35}, {80, 35, 
  0.4}, {80, 35, 0.45}, {80, 35, 0.5}, {80, 35, 0.55}, {80, 35, 
  0.6}, {80, 35, 0.65}, {80, 35, 0.7}, {80, 35, 0.75}, {80, 35, 
  0.8}, {80, 35, 0.85}, {80, 35, 0.9}};
```

[image: front]
[image: front][image: left][image: bottom][image: top][image: right]

I use ListPlot3D, but I can not get the right result. 
[image]

the other faces are missing.
How can I combine these faces to form a 3D region.

Comment: The vertical faces are missing because `ListPlot3D` only plots the surface as $z(x, y)$. Multiple values of $z$ for the same $x$ and $y$ won't work.

Comment: Hi, Taiki. Thank you very much for your help. So how can I plot the 6 faces of the 3D region.

Comment: The answers in your previous question [#79313](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79313) don't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Show[DelaunayMesh[
Union[datafront, databack, datatop, databottom, dataleft, dataright]],
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
    Axes -> True,
    ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that at least one surfave (the one hidden here) is not convex (with respect to others).