# Set maximum space between elements in 3D mesh

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, mesh

A region in 3D space has been discretized to obtain a list of points.

The resulting `ListPointPlot3D` plot is:

[image]

I will like to obtain a mesh from these points, but the mesh should not connect points that are too far away from each other.

Using `ConvexHullMesh` and `BoundingRegion` directly gives the following result:

[image]

The mesh connects points that are far away, closing a part of the volume which must be concave. Is there a way to set the maximum distance between the nodes of the mesh?

The list of 3D points is available at: [Points](https://we.tl/t-kmHNKFFCJP)

Comment: You asked for `ConvexHullMesh` and you got it. You can of course refine it by applying `DiscretizeRegion` with a small setting for `MaxCellMeasure`. Want you obtain is the remeshed convex hull. But maybe you want to compute an [$\alpha$-shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape)?

Comment: In general, it is a very nontrivial problem to construct a mesh from just a point cloud.

Comment: Don't know much about meshing, but I guess I want to compute an alpha shape. How can I do this in _Mathematica_?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8812

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, Henrik Schumacher!

These two links helped me to solve this problem:

[Finding a concave hull](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8753/finding-a-concave-hull)

[Random discrete data 3D plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79313/random-discrete-data-3d-plot)

Adequately modifying this code by Taiki and Simon Woods was just what I needed:

```
tetrahedra = Level[MeshPrimitives[DelaunayMesh[data], 3], {-3}];
radius[p_] := Circumsphere[p][[2]];
radii = radius /@ tetrahedra;
alphashape[rmax_] := Pick[tetrahedra, radii, r_ /; r < rmax]
faces[tetras_] := Flatten[
   tetras /. {a_, b_, c_, d_} :> {{a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {a, c, d}, {b, c, d}}, 1];
externalfaces[faces_] := Cases[Tally[Sort /@ faces], {face_, 1} :> face];
radiusmax = 150;
polys = externalfaces@faces@alphashape[radiusmax];
Graphics3D[
  {EdgeForm[{Thin, Opacity[1/30, Black]}], Polygon@polys},
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
  Axes -> True,
  Boxed -> False,
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
  ViewPoint -> 1000 {-1, 1, -1}
]
```

The result is:
[image]

Further playing with the `rmax` parameter can yield even more refined results.