# RegionResize works improperly with different digital accuracy

Tags: regions, mesh

The data is copied from the output cell of my original data.

```
pts={{25.3232,93.3884,7.90173},{25.3232,93.3884,15.6372},{25.3232,101.869,15.6372},{25.3232,101.869,7.90173},{25.6231,93.3884,7.90173},{25.6231,101.869,7.90173},{25.6231,93.3884,15.6372},{25.6231,101.869,15.6372},{25.6231,111.391,15.6372},{25.6231,111.391,7.90173},{25.923,101.869,7.90173},{25.923,111.391,7.90173},{25.923,101.869,15.6372},{25.923,111.391,15.6372}};


meshTest=ConvexHullMesh@pts

RegionResize[meshTest,10]
```

works properly

But in my original raw mesh, it works improperly.

```
ptsOrignal={{25.323178174128376`,93.38837529045934`,7.90172510421934`},{25.323178174128376`,93.38837330947786`,15.637175854060626`},{25.323178174128376`,101.86875495322009`,15.637176769628931`},{25.323178174128376`,101.86875627387441`,7.901726019787645`},{25.623105100248882`,93.38837529045934`,7.90172510421934`},{25.623105100248882`,101.86875627387441`,7.901726019787645`},{25.623105100248882`,93.38837330947786`,15.637175854060626`},{25.623105100248882`,101.86875495322009`,15.637176769628931`},{25.623105100248882`,111.39085617922113`,15.637177685197237`},{25.623105100248882`,111.39085882052977`,7.901727850924257`},{25.923034314647705`,101.86875627387441`,7.901726019787645`},{25.923034314647705`,111.39085882052977`,7.901727850924257`},{25.923034314647705`,101.86875495322009`,15.637176769628931`},{25.923034314647705`,111.39085617922113`,15.637177685197237`}};


meshTest=ConvexHullMesh@ptsOrignal

RegionResize[meshTest,10]
```

So is it a bug?

===
Since RegionResize is probably implemented by TransformedRegion.

This problem also happen in TransformedRegion.

`TransformedRegion[meshTest,ScalingTransform[{0.01,2,0.9}]]`
Works Fine

`TransformedRegion[meshTest,ScalingTransform[{0.01,2,0.8}]]`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Strange. Remove this point and the error goes away: ```{25.623105100248882`, 101.86875495322009`, 15.637176769628931`}```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`FindMeshDefects`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMeshDefects.html) shows that the second example produces "tiny faces".  You can use [`RepairMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepairMesh.html) as clean up step to remove such errors like so:

```
meshTest = ConvexHullMesh@ptsOrignal
FindMeshDefects[meshTest]
meshTest = RepairMesh[meshTest];
RegionResize[meshTest, 10]
```

[image: Repaired Mesh]

Comment: Thanks for your digging. The bad thing is RepairMesh will sometimes broke the shape of the model.

Comment: TransformedRegion[mesh,ScalingTransform[{0.01,2,0.9}]] works fine.
TransformedRegion[mesh,ScalingTransform[{0.01,2,0.8}]] failed

Comment: @HyperGroups They both worked on my machine `12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)` after I repaired the mesh.  If you want more options to repair the mesh, have you looked at MeshLab?  I posted an answer [214907](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/224563/61809) on how to decimate a mesh from _Mathematica_ calling MeshLab.