# Problems manipulating 3d Show[] output with multiple 3d objects

Tags: performance-tuning, graphics3d

My situation is as follows. I have two 3d objects, one created inside Mathematica and the second an imported STL file, that I want to superimpose and view together inside Mathematica. I want to be able to manipulate them visually, as in the things you can do with a 3d output in Mathematica by clicking and dragging with a mouse.

Now, the two objects can be manipulated normally. However, when I superimpose them and try to do this, it makes Mathematica lag considerably! There is no smooth movement at all; I just see the end product of a mouse drag after waiting for 5-10 seconds.

Can someone please tell me what is going on? Here are example objects:

```
obj1
```

[image]

```
obj2
```

[image]

and plotted together using `Show[]`:

```
comparison = Show[obj1, obj2];
Show[%, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

It is this third one that I have problems manipulating. Any suggestions?

Comment: Without examples of `obj1` and `obj2` to work with, this may not be answerable. Can you, please, update your question with this information? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that there is a whole notebook worth of content needed to make `obj1`. But let me see what I can do

Comment: You might also try not wrapping it with `Show` before you again wrap it with `Show`. Perhaps this is causing issues.

Comment: I found the answer to my question in this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214907/reduce-quality-of-an-imported-meshregion. The problem is that the imported STL is too large. I decimated the mesh using MeshLab, and my problem was solved! Should I state this as a proper answer below, or just delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question in this post: [Reduce quality of an imported MeshRegion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214907/reduce-quality-of-an-imported-meshregion).

The problem is that the imported STL is too large. I decimated the mesh using MeshLab, and my problem was solved!