# Issue plotting/re-creating 3d function

Tags: plotting, functions, graphics3d

I am trying to re-create images created in Mathematica using the equations in the photos attached.

[image: Equations]

[image: Images]

I was able to somewhat plot the Equation 6 (Cartesian coordinates) Figure 4 using this code

```
a=1;
A=-3;
c=0.2;
B=1;
epsilon=10^-5;
term1num=(x^2+y^2);
term1den=(a-A*((y^2*(3*x^2-y^2))/(x^2+y^2)^3)^B)^2;
term1=term1num/term1den;
term2=(1+epsilon-(z^2/c^2));
term3=z^2/c^2;
ContourPlot3D[1==term1*term2+term3,{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2},{z,-.05,.05}]
```

But the result doesn't look like Figure 4 from the paper I am referencing (Three-dimensional Representations of Hexagonal Ice Crystals and Hail Particles of Elliptical Cross Section, Wang, PK 1999).

I also don't know how to go about trying to plot this (Equation 8) in spherical coordinates in Mathematica.

I am new to the stack exchange and appreciate any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you new to Mathematica? To produce plots similar to those in the paper requires some trick (and cheat):

```
a = 1;
A = -3;
c = 0.2;
B = 1;
plotpoints = 50;
epsilon = 10^-5;
term1num = (x^2 + y^2);
term1den = (a - A*((y^2*(3*x^2 - y^2))/(x^2 + y^2)^3)^B)^2;
term1 = term1num/term1den;
term2[z_] := (1 + epsilon - (z^2/c^2));
term3[z_] := z^2/c^2;
sort[points_] := SortBy[points, N[ArcTan @@ (# - Mean[points])] &];
contour[z_] := ContourPlot[
  1 == term1*term2[z] + term3[z],
  {x, -2, 2},
  {y, -2, 2},
  PlotPoints -> plotpoints
];
Graphics3D[
  {
    EdgeForm[Thickness[Medium]],
    FaceForm[],
    Table[
      Polygon[sort@Cases[contour[z], {_Real, _Real}, -1] /. {x_Real, y_Real} -> {x, y, z}],
      {z, -5/100, 5/100, 1/100}
    ]
  },
  Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"},
  Boxed -> False,
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/4},
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, None},
  ViewPoint -> {1000, 800, 1000}
]
```

[image: Fig 4]

With

```
a = 1;
A = 0.1339;
c = 1;
B = 0.397;
plotpoints = 10;
```

[image: Fig 2]

What I did was

- using `ContourPlot` to produce a 2D plot for a particular `z`
- extracting the points from the plot using `Case` (at level `-1` only)
- sort the points clockwise around their centre ([#48105](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48105/5906))
- using `Polygon` to draw a closed line from the points
- producing several such polygons with `Table`
- combining them with `Graphics3D`

The method works only in case of one contour line per 2D plot though. It breaks down when, for example, `plotpoints = 50` in the second example above. To accommodate the possibility of more contour lines per plot, use the following code instead:

```
a = 1;
A = 0.1339;
c = 1;
B = 0.397;
plotpoints = 50;
epsilon = 10^-5;
term1num = (x^2 + y^2);
term1den = (a - A*((y^2*(3*x^2 - y^2))/(x^2 + y^2)^3)^B)^2;
term1 = term1num/term1den;
term2[z_] := (1 + epsilon - (z^2/c^2));
term3[z_] := z^2/c^2;
zrange = Range[-5/100, 5/100, 1/100];
contour[z_] := ContourPlot[
  1 == term1*term2[z] + term3[z],
  {x, -2, 2},
  {y, -2, 2},
  ContourStyle -> {Black, Thickness[Medium]},
  PlotPoints -> plotpoints
];
Graphics3D[
  MapThread[
    Cases[
      #1,
      GraphicsComplex[pts_, rest__] :>
        GraphicsComplex[Function[pt, Append[pt, #2]] /@ pts, rest],
      -1
    ] &,
    {Table[contour[z], {z, zrange}], zrange}
  ],
  Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"},
  Boxed -> False,
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/4},
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, None},
  ViewPoint -> {1000, 800, 1000}
]
```

[image: Alternative version of Fig 2]

Note that if some of the original contours are not closed, they remain so. The  *cheat* mentioned at the beginning refers to the use of `Polygon` (to close the loop) and lower `plotpoints` (to get rid of other contours).

I don't know why the shapes aren't exactly like those in the paper.

As to your question about plotting Eq. 8, I guess it's going to be even more complicated as there is no built-in function for 3D contour plots in spherical coordinates.