# How do I get ConvexHullMesh to return polygons instead of triangle as surface mesh?

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry, mesh

I would need to identify the types of regular polygons forming the surface of a convex hull of 3D points.
If I e.g. take the following example of a regular polyhedron

```
ConvexHullMesh[N[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]]]
```

The convex hull routine returns a triangulated mesh surface. Is there any simple way to convince *Mathematica* to return the surface as polyhedrons (in this case pentagons) instead of a triangulation.

To illustrate the issue further, e.g if one applies

```
MeshCells[ConvexHullMesh[N[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]]], 2]
```

*Mathematica* only returns triangles.

If one applies

```
ConvexHullMesh[N[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]]] // FullForm
```

There is the option `"CoplanarityTolerance"`. But I do not know how to use it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you see the CoplanarityTolerance option?

Comment: Just look at the FullForm of the last ConvexHullMesh statement above. There you see the option Rule["CoplanarityTolerance", Automatic]. If one tries to use this option with a numerical parameter instead of Automatic an error is returned that this option is unknown...

Comment: Ah, that's inside `Method`, and it's for `BoundaryMeshRegion`, not for `ConvexHull` or `BoundaryMesh` ...

Comment: This question is related to [Construct a polyhedron from the coordinates of its vertices and calculate the area of each face](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235524/construct-a-polyhedron-from-the-coordinates-of-its-vertices-and-calculate-the-ar).

Comment: This generates the coordinates of even though it doesn't use convexhullmesh, it uses the 3D convexhull: PolyhedronCoordinates[RandomPolyhedron[{"ConvexHull", v}]], which be be used to make the faces easier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The procedure groups triangles based on the same unit normal vector, then uses the vertices in each group to form a new polygon. The vertices are sorted in such a way that their polygon is not self-intersecting.

This method doesn't allow for coplanar tolerance. Triangles in the same group have the same unit normal vector determined to within the second argument of `Round` (`10^-5` here).

The sorting function `sort` is modified from [#48091](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48105/5906), which is a 2D method. `sort` uses the XY-projection of the points, unless they're colinear in X or Y.

```
sort[pts_] := Module[
  {p, subspaceselector},
  p = coord[[#]] & /@ pts;
  subspaceselector = Which[
    p[[1, 1]] == p[[2, 1]] == p[[3, 1]], Rest,
    p[[1, 2]] == p[[2, 2]] == p[[3, 2]], Drop[#, {2}] &,
    True, Most
  ];
  SortBy[pts, N[ArcTan @@ subspaceselector[coord[[#]] - Mean[p]]] &]
];
unitnormal[verts_] := Round[
  Normalize[Cross[verts[[2]] - verts[[1]], verts[[3]] - verts[[1]]]],
  10^-5
];
convexhull = ConvexHullMesh[N[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]]];
coord = MeshCoordinates[convexhull];
trivertices = Level[MeshCells[convexhull, 2], {-2}];
polysets = GatherBy[
  trivertices,
  unitnormal[Function[i, coord[[i]]] /@ #] &
];
polyvertices = Map[sort][Union @@ # & /@ polysets];
MeshRegion[coord, Polygon /@ polyvertices]
```

[image: New convex hull]

Comment: It doesn't quite work well for `"Cube"` instead of `"Dodecahedron"`.  The face vertices are not well ordered.

Comment: In principle, two distinct faces of a polyhedron can have the same normal.  But that will never happen if the polyhedron is a convex hull.  So the idea should work well.

Comment: Yes, I do rely on that assumption.

Comment: I'm coding proper `sort` now...

Comment: DONE! The code should work with anything now. Thank you @Szabolcs.

Comment: @Taiki. NICE work thanks for putting this online....

Comment: @Taiki Your solution seems to only work for named polyhedron. If it is a random polyhedron, it does not seem to work. For example if you set v = 20;randomPoints = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {v, 3}];convexhull = ConvexHullMesh[randomPoints];.

Comment: @TegLouis Hmm weird. The code with your `convexhull` still works on my machine running Mathematica 13.1.

Comment: Yeah, I am noticing that the wolframcloud version is not ideal for many reasons.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution that uses undocumented functionality to generate an appropriate `MeshRegion[]` object:

```
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];
FirstCase[ConvexHull3D[N[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]],
                       FlatFaces -> False], 
          GraphicsComplex[pts_, stuff_] :>
          MeshRegion[pts, Cases[stuff, _Polygon, ∞]], ∞]
```

[image: dodecahedron as a MeshRegion[]]

Answer (score 4):

Somewhere around version 12+ `ConvexHullMesh` now returns the desired output out of the box:

```
ConvexHullMesh[N[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]]]
```

[image]

If you're not on a recent enough version you can use `` Region`Mesh`MergeCells ``:

```
tris = RegionBoundary[DelaunayMesh[N[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]]]]
```

[image]

```
Region`Mesh`MergeCells[tris]
```

[image]

Comment: Will that work for an unnamed polyhedron? Like for when using RandomPolyhedron? I will check when I get home.

Comment: I would think so.

Comment: For wolfram cloud, it didn't work for an unnamed polygon. And the documentation for "PolyhedronData" says under possible issues that "Using nonstandard polyhedron names will not work". (I think this was a weird choice on Mathematica's part.) But I found out that PolyhedronCoordinates[RandomPolyhedron[{"ConvexHull", v}]] works where v is the number of vertices. While it doesn't use the term "ConvexHullMesh". I think it is worth noting this for this question since it is very related.