# Extra Lines in 3D ConvexHullMesh

Tags: mesh

I would like to make a picture of a truncated octahedron using ConvexHullMesh as follows:

`ConvexHullMesh[{{3, 1, 1}, {1, 3, 1}, {1, 1, 3}, {-3, -1, 1}, {-1,-3, 1}, {-1, -1, 3}, {-3, 1, -1}, {-1, 3, -1}, {-1, 1, -3}, {3, -1,-1}, {1, -3, -1}, {1, -1, -3}}]`

This gives a picture in which the hexagonal faces are subdivided into triangles. How to I make an image with no extra lines on the hexagons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the undocumented option `FlatFaces -> False`:

```
ConvexHullMesh[{{3, 1, 1}, {1, 3, 1}, {1, 1, 3}, {-3, -1, 1}, {-1,-3, 1},
     {-1, -1, 3}, {-3, 1, -1}, {-1, 3, -1}, {-1, 1, -3}, {3, -1,-1},
     {1, -3, -1}, {1, -1, -3}}, 
   FlatFaces -> False]
```

[image]

I learned about this option for the function `ConvexHull3D` from [this answer by J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97018/125). It also works with `ConvexHullMesh`.