# Construct a polyhedron from the coordinates of its vertices and calculate the area of each face

Tags: graphics3d, geometry, polyhedra

I have the 3D coordinates for a set of points. I want to construct the convex polyhedron with those points as vertices.

I know I can use functions like `DelaunayMesh` or `TetGenConvexHull` (`ConvexHullMesh` doesn't work for me because it sometimes generates wrong polyhedra) but when I plot the polyhedron there are always “extra edges” on each face, deriving from the triangulation. **I wonder if I can get rid of them.**

I also would like to get access to each face (without those extra edges) individually to **calculate their area**. How could I achieve this?

```
q={{-10., -7.5, -6.25}, {-10., -7.5, 6.25}, {-10., 0., -10.}, {-10., 0.,
   10.}, {-10., 7.5, -6.25}, {-10., 7.5, 
  6.25}, {-1.66667, -11.6667, -8.33333}, {-1.66667, -11.6667, 
  8.33333}, {2.5, -13.75, 0.}, {-2.5, 
  0., -13.75}, {1.66667, -8.33333, -11.6667}, {-2.5, 0., 
  13.75}, {1.66667, -8.33333, 11.6667}, {-1.66667, 
  11.6667, -8.33333}, {1.66667, 8.33333, -11.6667}, {-1.66667, 
  11.6667, 8.33333}, {1.66667, 8.33333, 11.6667}, {2.5, 13.75, 
  0.}, {10., -10., 0.}, {10., -6.25, -7.5}, {10., -6.25, 7.5}, {10., 
  6.25, -7.5}, {10., 6.25, 7.5}, {10., 10., 0.}};

DelaunayMesh[q]

Needs["TetGenLink`"]
{vertex, surface} = TetGenConvexHull[q[[1]]];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], GraphicsComplex[vertex, Polygon[surface]]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: 3d graphical output of DelaunayMesh]

[image: 3D graphical output from the results of TetGenConvexHull]

Comment: `DelaunayMesh[q]` fails without an error message in V12.2 (MacOS).  I guess it's a bug?

Comment: This question is very related to: [How do I get ConvexHullMesh to return polygons instead of triangle as surface mesh?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96970/how-do-i-get-convexhullmesh-to-return-polygons-instead-of-triangle-as-surface-me)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can use the function `` Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals `` to get face normals and group triangles by face normals:

```
ClearAll[combineCoplanarFaces]
combineCoplanarFaces[t_: 10^-3][bmr_ ] :=  Module[{faces = MeshPrimitives[bmr, 2],
    normals = Round[Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[bmr, 2], t]}, 
 Values @ GroupBy[Transpose[{normals, faces}], First -> Last, 
    Polygon@#[[Last @ FindShortestTour @ #]] & @ MeshCoordinates[RegionUnion@##] &]]
```

***Example:***

```
bdm = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@DelaunayMesh[q];


Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Thick], Hue @ RandomReal[], #} & /@ combineCoplanarFaces[][bdm], 
 Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**Update:** `` Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals `` is undocumented.

What we know about it is limited to what `` Information @ Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals `` returns; that is, it takes an option `Method`:

```
Information @ Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals
```

[image]

Through trial/error, we find that it takes two arguments; the first argument is a`MeshRegion` or a `BoundaryMeshRegion` object and the second argument is (1) an integer indicating mesh cell dimension (`0` for `Point`s, `1` for `Line`s and `2` for faces) or (2) a pair of integers `{dim, index}` indicating mesh cell index or (3) a list of integer pairs `{{dim1, index1}...}`.

So for mesh cells with indices `{0, 5}`, `{1, 4}`and `{2, 15}` we get

```
Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[bdm, {{0, 5}, {1, 4}, {2, 15}}]
```

> ```
> {{-3.71093, 2.60535, -1.63299},
>  {0.486229, 0.464079, -0.740413}, 
>  {0.40825, 0.816495, 0.408249}}
> ```

```
indices = {{0, 5}, {1, 4}, {2, 15}}; 

Show[bdm, 
 Graphics3D[{AbsoluteThickness[5], AbsolutePointSize[15], #} & /@ 
   MapThread[{Darker@#3, FaceForm[Lighter@#3], #, 
      Line[{If[Head[#] === Point, #[[1]], Mean@#[[1]]], 
        If[Head[#] === Point, #[[1]], Mean@#[[1]]] + 3 Normalize @ #2}]} &, 
    {MeshPrimitives[bdm, indices], 
     Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[bdm, indices], 
    {Red, Green, Blue}}]],
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
Row[Table[Show[bdm, 
   Graphics3D[{AbsoluteThickness[5], AbsolutePointSize[15], 
       Darker[rc = RandomColor[]], FaceForm[Lighter@rc], #} & /@ 
     MapThread[{#, Line[{If[i == 0, #[[1]], Mean@#[[1]]], 
          If[i == 0, #[[1]], Mean@#[[1]]] + 3 Normalize @ #2}]} &, 
       {MeshPrimitives[bdm, i], Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[bdm, i]}]], 
   ImageSize -> Medium], 
  {i, 0, 2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: That is a perfect approach. Thanks for helping!

Comment: But it seems that there is no documentation for function "Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals". Could you please explain how it works?

Comment: @Dennis, it is undocumented. I updated with some info that i found thru trial/error.

Comment: That's clear and very helpful! Thanks so much!

Comment: I just implemented this method and also try to use function `Area` to find out the area of each face after grouping the faces with the same normal together. However, the `Area` (or `RegionMeasure`) function only works on some of the faces (polygons). A lot of the polygons won't be taken by `Area` to generate the result. I can't see why. For example, this issue pops up by using the vertex coordinates posted in the original question. Could you also clarify why this happens?

Comment: @Dennis, try `Area@DiscretizeGraphics[Rationalize@#] & /@ 
 combineCoplanarFaces[][bdm]`

Comment: Although I am still confused about why, that indeed works..

Comment: I think it has to do with the faces not being  _exactly_  co-planar (we identified face normals within 10^-3 of each other as equal).

Answer (score 11):

*[Update: `combinepolys` now works when face meshes have interior vertices.]*

Start by getting the bounding polygons:

```
reg = DelaunayMesh[q]

bdypolys = Cases[Normal@Show[
    BoundaryMesh[reg]
    ], _Polygon, Infinity]
```

We group coplanar polygons into faces (`Tolerance` may need adjustment in other cases):

```
coplanarQ[pts_?MatrixQ] := 
  MatrixRank[Transpose@pts - pts[[1]], Tolerance -> 10^(-4)] == 2;

faces = RegionUnion @@@ 
   Gather[bdypolys, 
    coplanarQ[Flatten[{##} /. Polygon -> Identity, 1]] &];
```

We can get the areas:

```
Area /@ faces
```

> ```
> (*
>   {243.75, 174.693, 117.372, 117.372, 117.372, 117.372, 243.75, 
>   117.372, 174.693, 174.693, 117.372, 174.693, 117.372, 117.372}
> *)
> ```

The function `combinepolys` probably has horrible time complexity.  On this small example, it's no problem.  The trouble is that a common edge might be at the end points of the list of vertices of a polygon or consecutive entries.  To combine two adjacent polygons, we need to match each of the four possible combinations.

```
combinepolys = # //. {
     {x___,
       {p___, a_Integer, b_Integer, q___}, y___,
       {s___, b_, a_, r___}, z___} :> {x, {p, a, r, s, b, q}, y, z},
     {x___,
       {p___, a_Integer, b_Integer, q___}, y___,
       {a_, r___, b_}, z___} :> {x, {p, a, r, b, q}, y, z},
     {x___,
       {b_Integer, p___, a_Integer}, y___,
       {s___, b_, a_, r___}, z___} :> {x, {b, p, a, r, s}, y, z},
     {x___,
       {b_Integer, p___, a_Integer}, y___,
       {a_, r___, b_}, z___} :> {x, {b, p, a, r}, y, z},
     (* update: cut out singular edges *)
     {x___, a_Integer, b_Integer, a_, y___} :> {x, a, y},
     {b_Integer, a_Integer, x___, a_} :> {a, x},
     {a_Integer, x___, a_, b_Integer} :> {a, x}
    } &;

Show /@ faces // combinepolys (* shows each individual face *)

Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}],
     {RandomColor[], Cases[Normal@#, _Polygon, Infinity]}
     }] & /@ combinepolys[Show /@ faces];
Show[%]
```

> [image]

Comment: That's exactly what I expected. Thank so much! I didn't know about "combinepolys" before and I will need to try understanding how this function works.

Comment: @Dennis You're welcome.  `combinepolys` works on indices found in `MeshRegion`/`GraphicsComplex`.  In `combinepolys[{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 5}}]` there are two triangles that share an edge between vertices `2` and `3`.  The result is a quadrilateral `{{1, 2, 5, 3}}`.  I thought I wrote such a function years ago or discovered a built-in one, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Michael, Loved your solution! I’d been thinking about a way of identifying and merging co-planar faces since I read the question, but I came up empty. I’m relieved :-)

Comment: I obtained somewhat different results, making use of Maple. See [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mke8owutvwhedqd/poly.pdf?dl=0). The same is obtained with three digits.

Comment: A typo in the code (It should be `[[-10., -7.5, -6.25]]` instead of `[-10., -7.5, -6.2]`.) causes the difference. Correcting the typo, the results by Maple coinside with the results of the answer under consideration. See [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/huz3jpi62r43rc5/poly2.pdf?dl=0).

Answer (score 7):

We use [`FindShortestTour`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindShortestTour.html) to order the coordinates for each group of co-planar polygons:

```
ClearAll[coPQ, triangleCombine]

coPQ[x_, y_, t_: 10^-4] := Max[RegionDistance[InfinitePlane[x[[1]]], #] & /@ y[[1]]] <= t

triangleCombine[t_: 10^-4] := Module[{mc = MeshCoordinates[RegionUnion@##] & @@@ 
   Gather[MeshPrimitives[#, 2], coPQ[##, t] &]}, 
 Polygon @ #[[FindShortestTour[#][[2]]]] & /@ mc] &;
```

***Example:***

```
bdm = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@DelaunayMesh@q;

gathered = Gather[MeshPrimitives[bdm, 2], coPQ];

Tally[Length /@ gathered]
```

> ```
>  {{4, 2}, {3, 12}}
> ```

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[AbsoluteThickness[3]], RandomColor[], #}& /@ triangleCombine[][bdm],
  ImageSize -> Large, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

***Note:*** We could have also defined `coPQ` using MichaelE2's `coplanarQ` as

```
coPQ = coplanarQ[Join[#[[1]], #2[[1]]]]&
```

Answer (score 5):

It would be nice to be able to get the region boundary as a polygon or a (single) line in terms of the region.  `BoundaryMesh` does not work on surface regions in 3D.  In 2D, `BoundaryMesh` drops unused vertices, so you have to map the points in the boundary back to the points in original mesh to get the relation between them.  This is needed if you project the face onto 2D coordinate system (parallel to the face plane, for instance.

The advantage in this approach is that it works when there are points in the interior of the faces in the original mesh. Here the setup is similar to my other answer except for the subdivided mesh:

```
reg = DiscretizeRegion[ConvexHullMesh[q]]; (* subdivides OP's example *)

bdypolys = Cases[Normal@Show[BoundaryMesh[reg]], _Polygon, Infinity];

Length@bdypolys
(*  754  <-- DelaunayMesh gives 44 *)

coplanarQ[pts_?MatrixQ] := (* same as my other answer *)    
  MatrixRank[Transpose@pts - pts[[1]], Tolerance -> 10^(-4)] == 2;
faces // Length
(*  14  <-- same as before *)
```

See below for the utilities `boundingPolygon` and `findNormalProjection`, which I think I might find useful in other work:

```
Graphics3D[{
  EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}],
  {RandomColor[], boundingPolygon[#]} & /@ faces
  }]
```

[image]

Utilities:

```
boundingPolygon[mr_MeshRegion] := 
  Module[{coords, proj, mesh2d, bmesh, idcs, invproj},
   coords = MeshCoordinates[mr];
   proj = findNormalProjection[coords];
   invproj = Nearest[coords.proj -> coords];
   mesh2d = MeshRegion[coords.proj, MeshCells[mr, 2]];
   bmesh = BoundaryMesh[mesh2d];
   GraphicsComplex[
    Flatten[invproj@MeshCoordinates[bmesh], 1],
    MeshCells[bmesh, 2]
    ]
   ];

ClearAll[findNormalProjection];
findNormalProjection // Options = {Tolerance -> 0.001}; (*
 * In an exact solution the matrix rank will be 2
 * In an approximate solution there may be two large
 *   and several small nonzero singular values 
 * If more than two singular values are large
 *   then the points are not coplanar
 *)
findNormalProjection[pts_, OptionsPattern[]] /; Length[pts] >= 3 :=
  Module[{u, w, v, centroid, mat, proj, orientation},
  centroid = Mean[pts];
  mat = Transpose@pts - centroid;
  {u, w, v} = SingularValueDecomposition[mat];
  proj = u[[All, 1 ;; 2]]; (* u[[All,3]] = normal to plane *)
  orientation = Cross[mat[[All, 1]].proj].(mat[[All, 2]].proj);
  If[orientation < 0,
   proj = proj.{{0, 1}, {1, 0}} (* reflect *)
   ];
  proj /;
   Count[Diagonal[w], s_ /; s > OptionValue@Tolerance] == 2
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

A long time ago, 25/04/1998, I wrote my own ConvexHull3D package. It returns the hull as:

```
{{1, 3, 10, 11, 7}, {1, 7, 9, 8, 2}, {2, 8, 13, 12, 4}, {3, 5, 14, 15,
   10}, {4, 12, 17, 16, 6}, {5, 6, 16, 18, 14}, {7, 11, 20, 19, 
  9}, {8, 9, 19, 21, 13}, {10, 15, 22, 20, 11}, {12, 13, 21, 23, 
  17}, {14, 18, 24, 22, 15}, {16, 17, 23, 24, 18}, {1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 
  3}, {19, 20, 22, 24, 23, 21}}
```

and, since your coordinates are integers divided by 12, you can even get exact results for volume, area(s) and Steven Finch's Mean Width.
Volume = 16125/2, Areas are

```
{575/(2 Sqrt[6]), (625 Sqrt[5])/8, 575/(2 Sqrt[6]), 575/(
 2 Sqrt[6]), 575/(2 Sqrt[6]), (625 Sqrt[5])/8, 575/(2 Sqrt[6]), 575/(
 2 Sqrt[6]), (625 Sqrt[5])/8, (625 Sqrt[5])/8, 575/(2 Sqrt[6]), 575/(
 2 Sqrt[6]), 975/4, 975/4}
```

and MeanWidth is an ugly expression numerically equal to 26.7631.

For those who don't abhor 'ugly programming', the link is still http://users.telenet.be/Wouter.Meeussen/ConvexHull3D.m

Comment: The PolyhedralSets package of Maple works in higher dimensions too (see [here](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=PolyhedralSets&term=PolyhedralSets) for more info).