# How can I find polygons in convex hull?

Tags: regions, mesh, polyhedra

From some geometric computations I get a lot of 3 dimensional points. From theory I know two facts: The points define a convex polyhedron, and this polyhedron has non-regular 3-, 4- and 5-gons as faces.

Here is a simple example:

```
data = {
   {0.21737620787507367`, 0.28204133994445385`, -0.6381966011250104`},
   {-0.040325224750231564`, 0.3723248410400371`, -0.6275534829989065`},
   {0.1672600561785624`, -0.3071899418976666`, -0.623794735142785`},
   {-0.40371520600005606`, 0.10830656541096881`, -0.6045922471664844`},
   {-0.1656861048330671`, -0.4587939734903912`, -0.6045922471664844`},
   {0.20241349847734352`, 0.482246933272588`, -0.5386575383182851`},
   {-0.4222912360003364`, 0.40162283177245456`, -0.4281746070019348`},
   {0.0639979843841827`, -0.6963366498275445`, -0.3852375061707666`},
   {0.5124611797498108`, 0.019901688178267346`, -0.37150307459109644`},
   {-0.6832815729997477`, -0.4016228317724545`, -0.105572809000084`},
   {-0.5897762563863808`, 0.25456081688631615`, -0.05985083759092051`},
   {-0.047213595499958017`, -0.7951478980668848`, -0.047213595499957905`},
   {0.28885438199983166`, -0.6881909602355869`, -2.7755575615628914`*^-17},
   {-0.28885438199983166`, 0.6881909602355867`, 0.`},
   {0.04721359549995807`, 0.7951478980668849`, 0.04721359549995793`},
   {0.5897762563863808`, -0.25456081688631615`, 0.05985083759092051`},
   {0.6832815729997476`, 0.4016228317724544`, 0.10557280900008403`},
   {-0.5124611797498106`, -0.01990168817826732`, 0.37150307459109644`},
   {-0.06399798438418271`, 0.6963366498275444`, 0.38523750617076646`},
   {0.4222912360003364`, -0.4016228317724546`, 0.42817460700193477`},
   {-0.20241349847734355`, -0.4822469332725877`, 0.5386575383182852`},
   {0.165686104833067`, 0.4587939734903912`, 0.6045922471664844`},
   {0.403715206000056`, -0.10830656541096874`, 0.6045922471664844`},
   {-0.16726005617856243`, 0.3071899418976664`, 0.623794735142785`},
   {0.04032522475023116`, -0.37232484104003727`, 0.6275534829989065`},
   {-0.21737620787507372`, -0.282041339944454`, 0.6381966011250106`}
};
```

Display of the convex hull is easy:

```
cHullDetailled = ConvexHullMesh[data, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

or

```
cHullPolygons = ConvexHullMesh[data, PlotTheme -> "Polygons" ]
```

Images are nice and as expected:

[image: cHull1]
[image: cHullPolygons]

Faces of the meshes can be computed with:

```
polygonsDetailled = MeshPrimitives[cHullDetailled, 2];
Length[%]

(* 48 *)
```

and

```
polygonsPolygons = MeshPrimitives[cHullPolygons, 2];
Length[%]

(* 48 *)
```

In both cases the reported polygons are the SAME triangles. **How can I get the 4- and 5 -gons that I need for other computations instead?**

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Comment: I use Mathematica 12

Comment: Perhaps: Try to combine neighboring triangles with the same normal?

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: That is a possibility, but the second image shows that Mathematica has the answer internally. Is the no way to extract it?

Comment: related/possible duplicate: [Construct a polyhedron from the coordinates of its vertices and calculate the area of each face](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/235524/125)

Comment: does [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/235554/125) work for you?

Comment: @kglr: This looks good, probably, I will study in detail, thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Peter Hilgers I don't think the second image necessarily indicates that Mathematica's internal representation treats those polygons as separate. It could be that that with that plot theme it just doesn't render the edges of the (triangular) polygons.

Answer (score 4):

This works in version 12.2.0:

```
MeshCellCount[ConvexHullMesh[data],  2]
```

> ```
> 30
> ```

```
ConvexHullMesh[data,  MeshCellStyle -> { 1 -> Red}]
```

[image]

In earlier versions we get 48 triangles (co-planar triangles are not combined):

```
MeshCellCount[ConvexHullMesh[data], 2] (* version 11.3.0 *)
```

> ```
> 48
> ```

The following method (slightly modified version of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/235554/125)) works in both version 11.3.0 and  version 12.2.0:

```
ClearAll[combineCoplanarFaces]
combineCoplanarFaces[t_: 10^-3][bmr_] := Module[{faces = MeshPrimitives[bmr, 2], 
   normals = Round[Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[bmr, 2], t]}, 
  Values @ GroupBy[Transpose[{normals, faces}], First -> Last, 
    If[Length@# == 1, #, 
      Polygon@#[[Last@FindShortestTour@#]] &@
       MeshCoordinates[RegionUnion@##]] &]]

Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Thick], RandomColor[], #} & /@ 
   combineCoplanarFaces[][ConvexHullMesh[data]],
 Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this?:

```
chull = ConvexHullMesh[data];
polys = Cases[Show[chull], _Polygon, Infinity];
coords = First@
   Cases[Show@chull, GraphicsComplex[c_, ___] :> c, Infinity];

Graphics3D[
 GraphicsComplex[
  coords,
  {EdgeForm[Red], polys}
  ]]
```

[image]

The value of `polys` is in terms of indices into `coords`:

```
{Polygon[{{18, 11, 10}, ..., {26, 18, 10, 21}, ..., {2, 1, 3, 5, 4}}]}
```

To get the individual faces:

```
faces = Cases[Normal@gg, _Polygon, Infinity];

Graphics3D[ {RandomColor[], #} & /@ faces]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will do what you want.

First we create use `ConvexHullMesh`to create a `BoundaryMeshRegion` from your `data`. From this we then extract the 2-dim primitives, that is the triangles.

```
chm = ConvexHullMesh[data];
triangles = MeshPrimitives[chm, 2];
```

We now have all the triangles. If I understand you correctly, you want all faces that are composed from more tan one triangle. Toward this aim, we first gather all triangles with the same surface normal. This we store in the variable `mfaces`. The faces of only one triangle in `sfaces`. Note that there are 3 triangles in `sfaces` (No. 9,12,13) that are nearly in the same plane. This gave me a lot of trouble because it thought it they should be in `mfaces`.

```
nor[{p1_, p2_, p3_}] := (Sow[Normalize[Cross[p1 - p3, p2 - p3]]]; 
   Normalize[Cross[p1 - p3, p2 - p3]]);
faces = Gather[triangles, nor[#1[[1]]] == nor[#2[[1]]] &];
mfaces = Select[faces, Length[#] > 1 &];
mfaces = Select[faces, Length[#] > 1 &];
sfaces = Select[faces, Length[#] == 1 &];
```

Finally we plot all the faces that are no triangles:

```
Graphics3D[mfaces]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you all, I also found `Region`Mesh`MergeCells` as an undocumented function (sorry I lost the link).